# ppp0 connected but cannot route traffic

Tags: point-to-point-protocol

I have below ppp0 config under peers directory

```
pty "pptp vpnserveraddress.com --nolaunchpppd"
name vpnusername
password vpnpassword
remotename PPTP
require-mppe-128
defaultroute
usepeerdns
debug
```

after connecting the route does not get added with error
`not replacing existing default route via eth0_default_gw_route_ip`.

Also `ping -I ppp0 google.com`gives nothing.

What am I missing here in the config?

I am doing this on centos.

Comment: If you want to force replacing the default route (which may result in loosing connectivity), you have to use the ip-up script facility of pppd

Comment: Indeed.  I did that and as you said, i lost the connectivity.  I would first wish to get ping -I ppp0 working.  Otherwise making ppp0 the default route does not make any sense.

Comment: Told you :) You have to have a specific route for the vpn peer through your normal gateway. Then you can play with switching default route through vpn

Comment: Inspite of specific routes, why **ping -I ppp0 google.com** does not result anything.  I guess modifying the default route only makes sense once the above works smoothly?

Comment: True. For that ping to work, you have to get a valid and routed ip address on the ppp0 interface, from the vpn provider.